# Xts format of data.frame

Tags: r, type-conversion, xts

I have a dataframe with 2 columns in it. The first column contains POSIXct data, and the second contains some sample value integers. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to convert this dataframe to xts.

My data:

```
structure(list(SampleDateTime = list(1422835200000, 1423353600000, 
    1423958400000, 1433030400000, 1433635200000, 1434326400000, 
    1434844800000, 1444521600000, 1445731200000, 1453593600000, 
    1.455408e+12, 1420934400000, 1424563200000, 1425772800000, 
    1426982400000, 1430006400000, 1.431216e+12, 1.440288e+12, 
    1448150400000, 1460851200000), SampleValue = list(9L, 3L, 
    2L, 1733L, 19L, 6L, 1L, 17L, 7L, 23L, 147L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 
    1L, 19L, 1L, 11L, 2L, 91L), Dttm = structure(c(1107216000, 
1107734400, 1108339200, 1117411200, 1118016000, 1118707200, 1119225600, 
1128902400, 1130112000, 1137974400, 1139788800, 1105315200, 1108944000, 
1110153600, 1111363200, 1114387200, 1115596800, 1124668800, 1132531200, 
1145232000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c("feature$attributes", 
"feature$attributes1", "feature$attributes2", "feature$attributes3", 
"feature$attributes4", "feature$attributes5", "feature$attributes6", 
"feature$attributes7", "feature$attributes8", "feature$attributes9", 
"feature$attributes10", "feature$attributes11", "feature$attributes12", 
"feature$attributes13", "feature$attributes14", "feature$attributes15", 
"feature$attributes16", "feature$attributes17", "feature$attributes18", 
"feature$attributes19"), class = "data.frame")
>
```

I use this to try and make the conversion:

```
q <- as.xts(t, order.by = t$Dttm, dateFormat="POSIXct", frequency=NULL, RECLASS=FALSE)
```

I get the following errors:
Error in coredata.xts(x) : currently unsupported data type

Any help appreciated. I can't figure out why it says the DF is unsupported when it says they are in the documentation??

Comment: Your data format is not clear. Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(t)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(t, 20))`. Also, is the year of `47047-11-07` an error?

Comment: Something in your data seems odd. `SampleDateTime` and `SampleValue` are both a list of lists, not numeric variables, so xts dont know how to process them, hence the error.

Comment: Aren't all data frames list of lists?

Comment: They can be, but usually they are list of vectors, and that's what `as.xts` is expecting. As pointed in the answer below by @G.Grothendieck you need to unlist those variables before converting to xts. If you want to see the diference between a numeric or character variable and a list variable, you can play with the `starwars` dataset in the tidyverse. There you will find both types of variables to see the differences.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments your data is in a weird format in which the first two columns of the data frame are themselves lists rather than numeric columns so first unlist each column (this will not change any columns which are already not lists) giving `dat.u` and then convert.  We assume `dat` is the data shown via `dput` in the question.

```
dat.u <- replace(dat, TRUE, lapply(dat, unlist))
z <- read.zoo(dat.u, index = "Dttm")
x <- as.xts(z)
```